# css :hover not working as hoped in safari only, found some answers close, but none solve. Please Help :)

Tags: css, safari, hover, drop-down-menu

I have been scouring the forum for a few days now finding answers close to my issue, but none of them helped me solve it.

Some topics are close to this issue, so I apologize if I am repeating a question, but no one seems to be directly dealing with this one.

So I have a simple hover set on a `<div>` in a `<li>` to show another `<div>` in the same `<li>`

```
.flowerChoice { 
display: none;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
top:-17px;
}

.flowerShow:hover   {
height:100px;
width:100px;
}

.flowerShow:hover   div.flowerChoice {
display: block;
}
```

Then the html

```
<ul id="navlist">
    <li class="" >
       <a href="store.html">
           <img src="./images/nav-spacer.gif" />
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
         <div class="flowerShow">
             <a href="#">
                  <img src="./images/nav-spacer.gif" />
             </a>
             <div class="flowerChoice">
                 <img usemap="#flowerChoice" border="0" src="images/flowerChoice.png" />
                 <map name="flowerChoice">
                     <area shape="rect" coords="2,59,100,76" href="arrangements.html" alt="Flower Arrangements" />
                     <area shape="rect" coords="0,29,98,46" href="weddings.html" alt="Wedding Flower Arrangements" />
                 </map>
             </div>
         </div>
    </li>
    <li class="" >
        <a href="http://blog.passionflowerdesign.com/" alt="Passionflower Design Blog">
            <img src="./images/nav-spacer.gif" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="" >
        <a href="contact.html">
           <img src="./images/nav-spacer.gif" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When you mouse over the div then you get a second div that gives you a couple of links, it's basically a drop-down.

In all browsers, but Safari (I never had to fight safari) you can mouse over this area and it stays and let you get to the new links.

But in safari it closes before you can get to them.

I tried adding the hover to the `<a>` and to the `<li>` but then it breaks my code completely.

Any light shed on this is very appreciated!

http://www.thetclub.com/test/passionflower/www/index.html

Cheers!

Nate~

Comment: You really should be using javascript for this type of interaction.

Comment: Thanks DA, why would JS be better here? And thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: JS allows for much finer control over the interaction. And something like jQuery lets your code run more consistently across browsers. FYI, note that 'hover' might not be the best interaction for this anyways as it's hard to use on any touch devices.

Comment: I took your advice on this one, some simple show/hides, I was including jquery already, why not? Plus it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.flowerShow:hover li {
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

works for me in safari windows

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's a gap between the part you hover and the dropdown connected to it. Perhaps move the top up a bit further, but then add some additional top padding to make it look the same?